# how to remove p tag from wrapping every html element in shortcode

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

In my [wordpress project](http://109.74.4.178/svenskkinesiska/) I used shortcode to show the product listing. I have added html as below.

```
<article class="teaser product tepr prio ">
<a href="http://localhost/svenskkinesiska/resor/sichuans-parlor/">
<div class="itemwrap">
<img class="img-responsive " src="http://localhost/svenskkinesiska/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/banner2@2x-1920x740-c-center-373x239-c-center.png" srcset="http://localhost/svenskkinesiska/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/banner2@2x-1920x740-c-center-530x340-c-center.png 768w, http://localhost/svenskkinesiska/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/banner2@2x-1920x740-c-center-767x492-c-center.png 1400w" alt="SICHUANS PÄRLOR" />
<div class="itemtextwrap">
<div class="teprb">
<div class="middlecenter">
<h3><span>Sichuans pärlor</span></h3>
</div>
</div>
<span class="duration">8 DAGAR - </span><span class="price">fr 1:-</span></div>
<div class="cprice_cdays small">
<div class="tableBased">
<div class="tableCelled"><span class="cprice">8 dagar, pris från </span><span class="cdays">1</span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a></article>
```

But it's coming as below with extra p tag. I tried wpautop but to no avail. How to solve this ? Any help/suggestions are welcome.

```
<article class="teaser product tepr prio ">
<a href="http://localhost/svenskkinesiska/resor/sichuans-parlor/"></p>
<div class="itemwrap">
<img class="img-responsive " src="http://localhost/svenskkinesiska/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/banner2@2x-1920x740-c-center-373x239-c-center.png" srcset="http://localhost/svenskkinesiska/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/banner2@2x-1920x740-c-center-530x340-c-center.png 768w, http://localhost/svenskkinesiska/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/banner2@2x-1920x740-c-center-767x492-c-center.png 1400w" alt="SICHUANS PÄRLOR" /></p>
<div class="itemtextwrap">
<div class="teprb">
<div class="middlecenter">
<h3><span>Sichuans pärlor</span></h3>
</div>
</div>
<p><span class="duration">8 DAGAR - </span><span class="price">fr 1:-</span></div>
<div class="cprice_cdays small">
<div class="tableBased">
<div class="tableCelled"><span class="cprice">8 dagar, pris från </span><span class="cdays">1</span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p></a></article>
```

Comment: It is known `WordPress` issue, here are some solutions: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix, https://gist.github.com/bitfade/4555047

Comment: @SergeyLebedev both the solution didn't work. First solution did nothing while second solution just didn't show the html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery:

```
$("b").each(function() {
$(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
});
```

Note: this preserves whatever HTML you have inside where .text() might transform it.
If you wanted to quite literally just strip the  you can use:

```
$("p").html(function(i,h){ return h.replace(/<b>/g,'').replace(/<\/b>/g,''); });
```

or `result = str.replace(/(<p[^>]+?>|<p>|<\/p>)/img, "");`

Or try this:

```
 `var str = "Some awesome text with a <p class='myClass'>new paragraph</p> and more text.";

    var $temp = $("<div>").html(str);
    $temp.find("p").each(function() { $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes); });

    var output = $temp.html();`
```